# Is it possible to File.Copy a file into a system folder? like System32?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, file-permissions

I need to create files inside of a specific folder ("C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds") and possibly create said folder. When I try this with the File.Copy command windows won't grant the program permission, just throws an error. I am writing this in C# with VS2008.

EDIT: Windows 7, forgot about that part.

Comment: What OS are you seeing this on? Are you running as a non-administrative account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UAC. Have you added a manifest that requests elevated access? One of (don't ask me which...):

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

or

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

in the manifest file (`app.manifest`). The settings are discussed [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).